# Vimscript: fetch list of keymappings containing a prefix?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm adding a buffer-local mapping to close netrw windows:

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/netrw.vim
nnoremap <buffer> q <C-W>c
```

It works, but it hesitates because Netrw has created other mappings with a `q` prefix, namely `qb`, `qf`, `qF`, and `qL`, so it waits for the duration of `'timeoutlen'` before executing my mapping.

I want my `q` mapping to be instantaneous, so I've unmapped the other `q`-sequences:

```
nunmap <buffer> qb
nunmap <buffer> qf
nunmap <buffer> qF
nunmap <buffer> qL
```

But rather than hard-code these and have to update them if netrw adds more `q` mappings, I'd like to programmatically fetch a list of the keys my netrw buffer has mapped to sequences beginning with `q` and use that to drive the unmappings.

I suppose I could parse the output of `:nmap`, but that seems like a kludge. Is this information more directly accessible?

**UPDATE**

The answer provided below worked perfectly. It turns out, however, there's a way I can avoid the need to fetch these keybindings in the first place:

```
:help map-nowait
```

I came across this when reading through the [dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish/blob/master/ftplugin/dirvish.vim#L1) plugin. So rather then perform any `nunmap`s, I just changed my ftplugin file to:

```
nnoremap <nowait> <buffer> q <C-W>c
```

and it works right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: My mistake: Neither `getcompletion()` nor the old trick (see my [`lh#command#matchging_askvim()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/command.vim#L133) function) are able to return buffer-local mappings.

This means: I'm not aware of any way other than parsing  `execute('nmap q')` result. This means you'll may need to decrypt `@` and `*`. From `execute()` result, I'll simply extract the keybindings. Then, I'll use `maparg()` to have more precise information.

```
let keybindings = map(split(execute('nmap q'), '\n'), 'split(v:val, "\\W\\+")[1]')
let mappings =  map(copy(keybindings), 'maparg(v:val, "n", 0, 1)')
```

NB: in lh-vim-lib, I have other functions able to obtain mapping states and to restore them eventually. See [`lh#on#exit().restore_mapping_and_clear_now()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/on.vim#L155)

Comment: Nice. In my case I don't actually need the mappings, just the keys they were bound to, but I'm curious, in your `let mappings = ...` why are you making a copy of `keybindings`? Btw, I found your `lh#encoding#previous_character` and `lh#encoding#current_character` functions very useful recently. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you find my lib useful. It's one of its purposes :)
Regarding the copy, it's because I wanted to leave the variable unmodified and simply contain the string version of the key bindings. A one-liner without any copy would have worked. Otherwise, `map()` will transform these strings into dictionaries. The mapping definitions can be used to restore these definitions once you've finished. It really depends on the scenario. Sometimes we need to restore stuff to its previous definition.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `map()` was destructive like that. Ok cool